# What are some R packages for dealing with multivariate time series for data sets with multiple observations?

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-testing

I am trying to figure out how to approach a data problem that includes observations of multiple equipment units' pressure and temperature measures. The measures are available for a few years as daily or nearly daily values.

This seems like a time series problem (multivariate) and I have found some quality examples. However, because the data set consists of multiple measures taken for each equipment unit, I am a bit stumped on how to proceed. Should I fit a separate time series for each piece of equipment? This seems intuitively wrong, but I am really not sure which package or even approach I can use to work through this.

I would very much appreciate a recommendation or link to some resources.

Comment: Try to go through this list https://github.com/ropensci/hydrology

Comment: And this paper https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci-discuss.net/hess-2019-50/

Comment: Thanks, I will check out these links. I was hoping to find examples of how to predict readings from multiple pieces of equipment using time series (since past readings are available).